# How does $(n+1)! - 1 + (n+1)(n+1)! = (n+1)!(1+n+1) - 1$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> How does $(n+1)! - 1 + (n+1)(n+1)! = (n+1)!(1+n+1) - 1$?

I cannot figure this out, help. This deals with Mathmatical induction problem.
I've tried factoring but it doesn't work out.

Comment: You can only use induction if $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Hint: if you ignore $-1$ on both sides for a second, can you factor LHS?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that showing
$$(n+1)! - 1 + (n+1)(n+1)! = (n+1)!(1+n+1)-1$$
is equivalent to showing
$$(n+1)! + (n+1)(n+1)! = (n+1)!(1+n+1)\text{.}$$
(Simply add $1$ to both sides.) Now 
$$(n+1)!+(n+1)(n+1)! = (n+1)!(1+(n+1)) = (n+1)!(1+n+1)$$
after factoring, so we have solved the problem. If you are picky about how this looks, subtract $1$ to both sides.

Answer (score 2):

$(n+1)!-1+(n+1)(n+1)! = (1\cdot(n+1)!+(n+1)(n+1)!)-1
    = (n+2)(n+1)!-1 = (n+1)!(1+n+1)-1.$

Answer (score 1):

Set $K=(n+1)!$; then your expression becomes
\begin{align}
(n+1)! - 1 + (n+1)(n+1)! 
&=K-1+(n+1)K\\[6px]
&=K(1+n+1)-1\\[6px]
&=(n+2)K-1\\[6px]
&=(n+2)\cdot(n+1)!-1\\[6px]
&=(n+2)!-1
\end{align}
Note that the second line is exactly what you wanted to prove; I went on to show a further simplification.